# Css popover menu

Tags: html, css

I want to create popover menu when certain menu item is hover-ed, my menu is like this :

item1 | item2 | item3

When item2 is hovered I want to display popover below the item2 with arrow pointing upwards. I'm sure this is very easy to do using javascript although I haven't done it yet. But requirement here is to use CSS only.

I found this example :

http://demo.webinterfacelab.com/13-profile-popover/

Only difference is that I need for popover to show below the menu not above and arrow pointing upwards not downwards. Like in the image below :

[image]

Does anyone have example of how to do this? Or can help me to do this?

Comment: And what HTML are you working with? Where's the 'pop-over' coming from?

Comment: They used a custom CSS for that task. You should provide your own code/work, to be worked on.

Comment: You should explain why the sample you found hasn't given you enough info.  What confused you about it?  It doesn't use javascript.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Man, you must learn how to use inspector :) Trick is in `:after` and `:before` pseudo classes.

So, here is working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LPbhS/) of that tutorial, I've changed some CSS, check it out.

NOTE: This is CSS3 valid demo. Those pseudo classes will not work in older browsers, and you will not see arrow. Same is with transitions, and other CSS3 fancy things. If you don't want JS, you should be aware of that.

Comment: @Milan Puzovic thanks looks promising, but how do you specify the link on which you mouse over so the popover appears, in this case it's img

Comment: In this case, the whole menu is linked to element with class ".user". Check out CSS and relations between class ".user" and <ul> tags (that is menu). Relation is 

.user:hover ul {
visibility: visible;
opacity: 1;
padding: 4px 0 6px;
}... Apply that CSS on your classes.

Answer (score 8):

http://jsfiddle.net/9yeAJ/

The fiddle above illustrates just one way to do this. Hope it sets you on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Look into css3 transitions (animations). You will find great tutorials filled with hover transitions, and drop down menus.