# Using CSS3 Popover on <select> OR <option> Tags

Tags: jquery, css

Is there a way I can use CSS3 popovers on the `<select>` and `<option>` tags? Actually, I've already tried it on `<select>` tag and it works. But for `<option>` it doesn't. I was following an example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877625/css-popover-menu). Check out my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aHyTQ/) that was derived from the mentioned linked. I am interested in displaying an image using the popover when the user hovers on one of the options. Do I need to introduce jQuery to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: What’s a CSS3 popover?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite See this as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/9yeAJ/

Answer (score 3):

I assume what you're asking is if you can target the dropdown bit of a `select` using some selector and apply styling to it like the popover in the question you linked.

The answer is **sorta**.

The `select` HTML5 element is an example of a [Shadow DOM widget](http://glazkov.com/2011/01/14/what-the-heck-is-shadow-dom/) in action.

In short, the drop down that you're seeing is neither the `select` nor the `option` elements. It's a hidden element that can only be targeted using the Shadow DOM API.

As of now, the [shadow DOM spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-shadow-dom-20130514/) is a [working draft](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web_Consortium#Working_Draft_.28WD.29) that [most browsers haven't implemented](http://caniuse.com/shadowdom) at all. [Chrome is the only browser](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/01/content-security-policy-and-shadow-dom.html) (*as of May 2013*) that offers any substantial amount of Shadow DOM support.

Because of this, cross-browser pure CSS answers to your question involve 'hacks,' of sorts, [like the answers to this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript).

If you're against things like this – perhaps for [semantic reasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML) – then you should consider Javascript solutions. This Javascript solution might involve making your own HTML widget that behaves like a select, but is comprised of regular DOM elements, which you *could* control the style of. There are a number of feature-rich Javascript selects already in existence that you might want to try. [As an example, check out Chosen, one of my personal favorites.](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

If you want to prepare for the future, I suggest you check out the [Shadow DOM tutorials](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/) over at HTML5 Rocks. They're a good read.

Comment: Thanks @jmeas. I will have a look at these links. Yes, basically what I was trying to do was to show an 'image' using the popover when a user hovers on one of the options.

Comment: @kolor, showing an image? Where at in relation to the option? If you explain it in more depth, I may be able to provide more specific help.

Comment: Sure. The idea is when you hover on each `<option>`, an image would pop-up to the right to showcase what that option looks like visually. So for example, if I'm hovering over options like Toyota Camry, Mazda 6, and Honda Civic... it needs to show their respective images. Know what I mean?